# Is there a way to disable slick slider from autoscrolling when clicked on navigation slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

There's the `slider syncing` functionality that I need to use (can be seen here http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ when you scroll down a bit), but, as we can see, when you click on the navigation slide, the whole navigation autoslides further, I'd like to disable this functionality so that the main slide changes, but the navigation stays at the same level as it is until I click `next` or `previous` arrow.

Is there a setting for that or do I have to change the core to achieve this?

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/9kp36e09/ - so now if you click on navigation, it scrolls, I want to disable that scrolling.

Comment: You mean that if I click on slider #4 for example it centers itself automatically? if so look at the variable `centerMode: true,`

Comment: @odedta I've set that to false and it doesn't do what I need :(

Comment: @odedta added link to jsfiddle in post.

Comment: So basically, you want a static thumbnail bar?

Comment: @odedta yes, until a click on the `next` or `previous` is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76802/discussion-between-odedta-and-xeen).

Answer (score 11):

Well, it is not in the documentation, but I fixed it by add the `accessibility` to `false`.  e.g:

```
$('#sliders').slick({
    accessibility: false
});
```

Comment: `accessibility: false` in options only disables navigation with keyboard. Still the slider scrolls if any item is clicked

Answer (score 0):

set `focusOnSelect: false` for the nav.

I had the exact same problem and it worked. please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449209/disable-sliding-when-selecting-a-slide-in-slick-slider)

Answer (score 0):

`touchMove: false`

u can read in the doc : https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api