# Disable sliding when selecting a slide in slick slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

I am using syncing sliders

"fullslide" - 1 slide at a time

"thumbslide" - 5 slides at a time, used as nav for fullslide

when selecting 1 slide from thumbslide i want it to become active **without** sliding to the left or to the center. Is there a way to achieve this?

**CODE**

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    accessibility: false
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    accessibility: false
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9kp36e09/42/)

I tried:

```
$('#sliders').slick({
     accessibility: false
});
```

from: [Is there a way to disable slick slider from autoscrolling when clicked on navigation slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013101/is-there-a-way-to-disable-slick-slider-from-autoscrolling-when-clicked-on-naviga?rq=1)

still not working

Thank you

Comment: which plugins you are using for the sliders? and show us your code.

Comment: I am just using slick, added fiddle

Comment: how about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/9kp36e09/44/)?

Comment: Yes you got the behavior I want but... I need the nav to be a slider as well. But if all else fails you have given me an idea to just manually do it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same answer as on github:

First set focusOnSelect: false for the nav.

Second the main should not have asNavFor or more events will be needed.

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 5,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: false,
   centerMode: false,
   focusOnSelect: false
});

$('.slider-nav .slick-slide').on('click', function (event) {
   $('.slider-for').slick('slickGoTo', $(this).data('slickIndex'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7bkn5ym/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me and I didn't expect it to be that simple :)

Comment: I was just looking for the same functionality and this is good, but I need to use the synced active class to link the nav and slider. Do you know if that's possible somehow?

Comment: Worked for focusOnSelect thing which I forgot! Thanks, buddy

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, I just found a really easy way to disable scrolling - simply set the translate3d on `.slick-track` to this:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)!important;
```

Comment: This worked for me too! I actually set `transform: none !important` instead.

Comment: Nice one, this is exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: This will disable though the sliding when you click on the arrows and want to select the next not visible element.

Comment: @Georgios , use .flex-control-nav rather than .slick-track , this is working for me like  .flex-control-nav{ transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;}

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use draggable feature form Slick and turn it into false, it works for me:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: false,
fade: true,
asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
accessibility: false,
draggable: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used .flex-control-nav{ transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;}